# How to read continuously from the SerialPort

Tags: c#, win-universal-app

I need to read continuously the bytestream from my Arduino board.
For this, I've created a method that is reading the Serialport in a loop and  expose the ByteStream to the other classes:

```
public async void ReadSerialPort 
   {
     dataReader = new DataReader(SerialPort.InputStream)
     while (true) {
      uint ReadBufferLength = 16;

      Task < UInt32 > loadAsyncTask;


      loadAsyncTask = dataReader.LoadAsync(ReadBufferLength).AsTask();

      UInt32 rxbytes = await loadAsyncTask;

      RxBytes = new byte[rxbytes];
      if (rxbytes > 0) {
       datareader.ReadBytes(ByteStream);

      }
     }
    }
```

But I think this is not the most efficient method for reading the serialport continuously as this method needs a couple of milliseconds to get the bytestream. 
Is there an alternative for reading the bytestream?

Comment: why don't you use the event based approach? see [official docs](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.ports.serialport.datareceived(v=vs.110).aspx?cs-save-lang=1&cs-lang=csharp#code-snippet-2)

Comment: @RaphaelMüller That api is not available under UWP-Win10

Comment: have a look at https://create.arduino.cc/projecthub/DavidJones/windows-10-iot-windows-remote-arduino-and-universal-windows-14bab3

Answer (score 0):

Use event to read data from SerialPort:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    SerialPort sp=  new SerialPort();
    sp.DataReceived += Sp_DataReceived;
}

private static void Sp_DataReceived(object sender, SerialDataReceivedEventArgs e)
{
    throw new NotImplementedException();
}
```

Comment: Not working in UWP, the SerialPort class doesn't have a DataReceived property.